# FOREIGN KEY constraint failed in Django TabularInline

Tags: django

I have 2 models: Responsavel and Filho. Responsavel can have a lot of Filhos, so in my admin.py file i have the following:

```
class FilhoInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Filho

@admin.register(Responsavel)
class ResponsavelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
        FilhoInline
    ]

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        obj.user.is_pai = True
        obj.user.save()
        super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)
```

With this i can insert Responsavel and Filho in same screen, much more usable. So, in my models.py i have:

```
class Responsavel(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(TogetherUser, verbose_name="Usuário", primary_key=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    cpf = models.CharField(max_length=11, unique=True)
    telefone1 = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    telefone2 = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    telefone3 = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Responsáveis"
        verbose_name = "Responsável"

class Filho(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    data_nascimento = models.DateField(verbose_name="Data de Nascimento")
    genero = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=Genero.choices(), verbose_name="Gênero")
    responsavel = models.ForeignKey(Responsavel, on_delete=models.PROTECT, verbose_name="Responsável")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nome

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Filhos"
```

When i try to save the Responsavel  and your "Filhos" inside Admin Django i got the following error:

```
IntegrityError at /admin/core/responsavel/add/
FOREIGN KEY constraint failed
```

But if i add Responsavel without any "Filhos" everything works.

**Edit 1:**
I changed the models.PROTECT to models.CASCADE and it works, in this point:

```
responsavel = models.ForeignKey(Responsavel, on_delete=models.PROTECT, verbose_name="Responsável")
```

to

```
responsavel = models.ForeignKey(Responsavel, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="Responsável")
```

I have no ideia why this can impact in my save method if this is a "on_delete" and not "on_update" or something else.